# Network Pinging with Python

Tags: python, request

Is there a way i can ping requests of a particular website for a particular no. of times using Python and also is there a way through which i can decide  the no . of packets of  data to be send in each request ?

Comment: which version of python are you using ?

Comment: I hope this site is usefull for you since ur using python 3 <br>
The link is [here](http://www.falatic.com/index.php/39/pinging-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the os module for this.

5 is the count
www.examplesite.com is the site

```
import os

os.system("ping -c 5 www.examplesite.com")
```

Hope it helped

Comment: using os.system will probably result in difficult to maintain code since the ping utility might change.

Comment: how will i decide the no. of packets

Comment: `ping -c <number> <host>` you'll have to contstuct a string replace <number> with your number and host with host. but as I told this is difficult to maintain, since the ping utillity might not be on all platforms, might return different output, doesn't stop at some platforms etc.

Comment: `-c` flag raises `bad option` error on my windows 7 command prompt.  What is it supposed to do?